# Find duplicates per parent id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two DB tabels which form a parent child relationship from Planung to Aufgabe:

Planung:

```
CREATE TABLE `planung` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Bezeichnung` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   -- lots of ohter columns
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Aufgabe:

```
CREATE TABLE `aufgabe` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `planung_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL, -- foreign key to Planung.id
  `Nummer` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  -- lots of ohter columns
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

I'm looking for a query which gives me all Planung.id and Aufgabe.ID for all duplicate Nummer per Planung. Or in other words: For every Planung Aufgabe.Nummer must be unique, I want to check whehter this is really the case in my DB (I know it isn't).

Comment: You might consider using a unique index consisting of `planung_id, nummer` on the table `aufgabe`. (After you cleaned up of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT planung_id, GROUP_CONCAT(id) AS aufgabe_id, Nummer, COUNT(1) as num_duplicates
FROM aufgabe
GROUP BY planung_id, Nummer
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

This query gives all planung_id which has duplicate Nummer and displays them like:

```
planung_id aufgabe_id Nummer num_duplicates
1          2,5,8      1      3
```

Which means, for Planung 1, there exists three Aufgabe with Nummer 1, and they are 2,5 and 8.

**Edit**: Shamelessly stolen from [@dgw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1137055/dgw)'s comment:
Once you have run this query, and corrected all the duplicates. Add a unique index to `aufgabe {planung_id, Nummer}` to ensure that the database maintains this constraint:

```
ALTER TABLE aufgabe 
  ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE uq_planung_id_and_nummer (planung_id, Nummer)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select p.id, a.id, a.Nummer from planung p
inner join aufgabe a on a.planung_id = p.id
group by p.id, a.id, a.Nummer having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: yeah, i dunno what I was smoking, just leave out the a.id from select and group and you got one of the other answers

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all elements from planung being more than once a parent.

```
SELECT planung_id,nummer,COUNT(*)
  FROM aufgabe
 GROUP BY 1,2 HAVING COUNT(*)>1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you every `planung_id` that has multiple `Nummer` values:

```
SELECT planung_id
FROM aufgabe
GROUP BY planung_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Nummer) > 1
```

If you also need the `aufgabe.id`, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM aufgabe
WHERE
    planung_id IN (
        <query above>
    )
```

If you need to enforce that at all times, consider adding a key on `{planung_id, Nummer}` (as @dgw has already suggested).